# how to get arg from premain method in @Advice.OnMethodExit?

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents

```
public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        System.out.println("Agent for time measure:" + arg);
}
```

I want to get arg at below method, or arg is not use.
it is best, in OnMethodExit method get arg.

```
public class TimerAdvice3 {

    @Advice.OnMethodEnter
    static long enter(@Advice.Origin String method, @Advice.AllArguments Object[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpUriRequest httpUriRequest = (HttpUriRequest) args[1];
        System.out.println(httpUriRequest.toString());
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return start;
    }

    @Advice.OnMethodExit
    static void exit(@Advice.Origin String method, @Advice.Enter long start) throws Exception {
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("拦截======》" + method + " took " + (end - start) + " milliseconds ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to apply the advice that you wrote? You need to use the `AgentBuilder` API for this:

```
new AgentBuilder.Default()
  .type(...)
  .transform((builder, type, classLoader, module) -> builder.visit(Advice
     .withCustomConfiguration()
     .bind(MyAnnotation.class, arg)
     .to(TimerAdvice.class)
     .on(...))
  .installOn(instrumentation);
```

In your advice, you can now use:

```
static long enter(@Advice.Origin String method, 
    @Advice.AllArguments Object[] args, 
    @MyAnnotation String arg) { ... }
```

You can also use `@Advice.Argument(0)` if you wanted to only read `HttpUriRequest`. Just make sure to use `RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME`.

Comment: Maybe i didn't express clear.
I want to get argument,which is seted at -javaagent

Comment: I have implemented the method you said

Comment: no，I want to get argument,which is seted at -javaagent

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void premain(String arg, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        System.out.println("Agent for time measure:" + arg);

        FileWriter fileWriter = null;
        try {
            fileWriter = new FileWriter("./premain-arg");
            fileWriter.append(arg);
            fileWriter.flush();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fileWriter != null) {
                try {
                    fileWriter.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

this is my Solution，but I don't think it is perfect

Comment: No, it generates quite some overhead and file system operations might not always be allowed or possible. I recommend you to bind an annotation as suggested in my edited answer.

Comment: Succeed!
your method is perfect!